# variable connected to Interface builder not free memory when release it , how to fixed?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, interface-builder

this view controller will consume memory when the view dealloc all that memory are not free
how to free that memory ??

```
@interface Agro01ViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate> {

    NSInteger picIndex;
    BOOL isOverrideing;
    NSTimer *myTimer;
    NSInteger maxPicture;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *myscrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *myscrollView3;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *simgView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *simgView3;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *imgView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *imgView2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *imgView3;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *imgView4;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *imgView5;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *imgView6;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *imgView7;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *imgView8;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *Portrait;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *Landscape;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger maxPicture;

- (IBAction) Closebutton:(id)sender;
- (void)updatepicture;
- (IBAction) SecondViewbutton:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation Agro01ViewController
@synthesize imgView = _imgView, imgView2 = _imgView2, imgView3 = _imgView3, imgView4 = _imgView4, imgView5 = _imgView5;
@synthesize imgView6 = _imgView6, imgView7 = _imgView7, imgView8 = _imgView8, Portrait = _Portrait, Landscape = _Landscape ;
@synthesize myscrollView = _myscrollView, myscrollView3 = _myscrollView3, simgView = _simgView, simgView3 = _simgView3, maxPicture;
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"dealloc");
    [_Landscape release];
    [_Portrait release];
    [_imgView release];
    [_imgView2 release];
    [_imgView3 release];
    [_imgView4 release];
    [_imgView5 release];
    [_imgView6 release];
    [_imgView7 release];
    [_imgView8 release];
    [_myscrollView release];
    [_myscrollView3 release];
    [_simgView release];
    [_simgView3 release];
    [super dealloc];

}
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.simgView = nil;
    self.simgView3 = nil;
    self.myscrollView = nil;
    self.myscrollView3 = nil;
    self.Landscape = nil;
    self.Portrait = nil;
    self.imgView = nil;
    self.imgView2 = nil;
    self.imgView3 = nil;
    self.imgView4 = nil;
    self.imgView5 = nil;
    self.imgView6 = nil;
    self.imgView7 = nil;
    self.imgView8 = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    if (([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)) {
        self.Landscape.alpha = 1;
        self.Portrait.alpha = 0;
    }
    else {
        self.Landscape.alpha = 0;
        self.Portrait.alpha = 1;
    }
    [self.view addSubview:self.Landscape];
    [self.view addSubview:self.Portrait];


    self.myscrollView3.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.simgView3.frame.size.width, self.simgView3.frame.size.height);
    self.myscrollView3.maximumZoomScale = 1.0;
    self.myscrollView3.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    self.myscrollView3.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.myscrollView3.delegate = self;
    self.myscrollView3.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.myscrollView3.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    [self.myscrollView3 addSubview:self.simgView3];




    self.myscrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.simgView.frame.size.width, self.simgView.frame.size.height);
    self.myscrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0;
    self.myscrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    self.myscrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.myscrollView.delegate = self;
    self.myscrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.myscrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    [self.myscrollView addSubview:self.simgView];
    isOverrideing = NO;
    picIndex = 0;

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
self.simgView = nil;
self.simgView3 = nil;
self.myscrollView = nil;
self.myscrollView3 = nil;
self.Landscape = nil;
self.Portrait = nil;
self.imgView = nil;
self.imgView2 = nil;
self.imgView3 = nil;
self.imgView4 = nil;
self.imgView5 = nil;
self.imgView6 = nil;
self.imgView7 = nil;
self.imgView8 = nil;
[super viewDidUnload];
}
```

You're clearing out the pointers to the objects you want to get rid of, before the dealloc can take place.  Let the dealloc handle it.

joe

Comment: Thank you. i'm deleting it, let me test

Comment: If this fixes it, the correct solution is to make sure that your properties are defined as `retain`. The above code is correct and should be part of `viewDidUnload`.

Comment: Joe , memory still not free. any solution?

Comment: Rob Napier, i have change it to retain, but i don't know why the memory are not free when this view has dealloc

Comment: OK, I missed that you were using the accessors to handle the references.  So Rob is right that setting them to nil (using the accessors) will release the objects.  However, I'm not sure about the timing when you're getting these calls.  This is in your ViewController, so dealloc will only get called when the ViewController is released.  viewDidUnload will get called when your view is released, and is used to clean up any properties associated with the released view.  So which is it?  What's happened that makes you expect the memory to be released?

Comment: i have add image from IB, it will consume 50Mb when i release that view controller it still not free memory, then when i open many viewController it will increase size from 50 to 120, 200 and then OS kill it. I'm try to release that memory from IB , any idea?

Comment: Something is going wrong with your memory management of that image object.  My guess is it's being orphaned before you get to this point, so the release never gets to the right object.  I don't think the real problem is in the code you're showing.